# How to improve the HTML to use Razor HTML Helpers

Tags: c#, html, razor

The following HTML code is found in Index.cshtml--

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="Please choose your country "
                    id="Country" name="Country" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;" >
    <option value="">-- Select Country --</option >
    @foreach (var country in (List<Country>)ViewBag.AvailableCountries )
    {
      <option value="@country.Id">@country.Name</option >
    }
</select>
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Country "
data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Kindly improve the HTML to use **Razor HTML Helpers**, such as `DropDownListFor` and
`ValidationMessageFor`.

Comment: please improve what you are asking..., just use DropDownListFor. if you are asking how to use DropDownListFor,  then ask that...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your action.

```
var countries =new List<Country>(); //assign list of country here.
ViewBag.AvailableCountries =  countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Value = x.Id,
                                   Text = x.Name
                               }).ToList();
```

> I'm assuming you country class has property . (Id and Name)

Now in your view. you can use like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.County, ViewBag.AvailableCountries as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Add Required attribute on Country property in model class. so you don't need to add extra required class for select.